SFSpeechRecognitionResult discards previous transcripts when making long pauses
I've encountered same problem which is described in this thread. Since iOS 18, when I use SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest, returned not final SFSpeechRecognitionResult discards previously recognized transcriptions when I make longer pauses between speaking.
E.g. when I do this:

Say "Hello"
Make 5s pause
Say "how are you"
Finish recognition task

Partial results first return "Hello" and then "how are you" and final result returns just "how are you". This is problem since expected behavior (which worked on iOS 17) is that it returns the whole transcription "Hello how are you".
I create SFSpeechRecognitionRequest like this:
let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, when in
    request.append(buffer)
}

audioEngine.prepare()
try audioEngine.start()

and I create SFSpeechRecognitionTask like this:
recognizer.recognitionTask(
    with: request,
    resultHandler: { [weak self] result, error in
        self?.recognitionHandler(result: result, error: error)
    }
)

and then finally my recognition handler looks like this:
func recognitionHandler(result: SFSpeechRecognitionResult?, error: Error?) {
    if let result {
        let recognizedText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
        print(recognizedText)
    } else if let error {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

This seems to be correct based on provided Apple's example. So, what I do wrong?

As I understand it correctly, it seems like a bug on iOS 18 in case recognizer supports on device recognition (supportsOnDeviceRecognition).
As a workaround you can join final-partial results. You can identify that it is final-partial result by checking it is segments' confidence. When you decide it is final-partial result, you can append it to accumulator array. Then when you want to get recognized text, you need to join all those final-partial results sorted by speechStartTimestamp  with not-final-partial result.
So, on class/struct/actor scope, define array like this (don't forget to clear it when you do new recognition):
private var finalPartialRecognizedResults = [SFSpeechRecognitionResult]()

then change your recognitionHandler:
func recognitionHandler(result: SFSpeechRecognitionResult?, error: Error?) {
    if let result {
        let recognizedText = resolveCurrentlyRecognizedText(for: result)
        if result.isFinal {
            print("Final text:", recognizedText)
        } else {
            print("Final partial recognized results:", recognizedText)
        }

    } else if let error {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

func resolveCurrentlyRecognizedText(for result: SFSpeechRecognitionResult) -> String {
    if recognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition == true {
        let isFinalPartialRecognizedResult = (result.bestTranscription.segments.first?.confidence ?? 0) > .zero

        if isFinalPartialRecognizedResult {
            finalPartialRecognizedResults.append(result)
        }
        return getCurrentlyRecognizedText(
            notFinalPartialRecognizedResult: !isFinalPartialRecognizedResult ? result : nil
        )
    } else {
        return result.bestTranscription.formattedString
    }
}

func getCurrentlyRecognizedText(notFinalPartialRecognizedResult: SFSpeechRecognitionResult?) -> String {
    let finalResults = finalPartialRecognizedResults.sorted(
        by: {
            ($0.speechRecognitionMetadata?.speechStartTimestamp ?? 0)
            < ($1.speechRecognitionMetadata?.speechStartTimestamp ?? 0)
        }
    )
    let results = finalResults + [notFinalPartialRecognizedResult].compactMap { $0 }
    return results
        .map(\.bestTranscription.formattedString)
        .joined(separator: " ")
}


I have the same issue, thanks for sharing your idea!
How did you solve the problem with wrong uppercase / lowercase in between the segments, as they each got recognised as stand-alone sentences?
It's quite notably on upper/lowercase heavy languages like german for example.

@ehrpaulhardt unfortunately I didn't. We primarily use voice to voice communication so user doesn't need to see the text. And when user does, we use language model which corrects the recognized text.

Ahh i see. I my case the user can see all the text he spoke in. We use a chat flow in our app, where the user first talks into a chat-bubble. The final text then will feed a large language model to produce the chat response.
